# "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." without any meaningfull stack trace

Tags: apache-flex, exception, null

Regularly during my application run, I get

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.managers::SystemManager/stageEventHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.4.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:5649]
```

This is the **full** stack trace. Obviously, I guess there is something wrong, but I can't understand what.
Is there any way for me to find the origin of that bad behaviour ?

**EDIT**

Having added my SDK sources to my debugger, I can now say precisely which line it is :

```
    private function stageEventHandler(event:Event):void

    {

        if (event.target is Stage)

            mouseCatcher.dispatchEvent(event); // This is line 5649

    }
```

`mouseCatcher` is indeed `null`. The current event target is indeed a Stage object, and event type contains the `"deactivate"` String. As event occurs at application startup (before I try to do any kind of user interaction), I guess it's a kind of initialization bug, but where ? and why ?

Comment: did you check what in SystemManager.as line 5649 is? what does it reference there ... any clue? i'm not so much into flex, so i don't know the `SystemManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code, this is always your best option.  The 3.4 SDK is open source (datavisualization and the flash player itself aside) and you probably already have the source for it in your FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder install/sdks folder.  Use grep or windows grep to find the file in question (or find, whatever floats your boat).  Open the SystemManager file and check what's happening at that line, check for calls to the method (if it's public use grep again, if it's private you just need to look within the SystemManager).  Try to understand why it gets to this point, as pointed out by some others it's likely a timing related issue where you're trying to access something before it has been assigned, in this case the SystemManager, you probably need to defer whatever action you're taking that is causing the error to a later part of the life-cycle (if you're using initialize event or pre-initialize try on creationComplete instead since that will be dispatched after the createChildren method is called).

Note: Mine is located here

C:\CleanFS\SDKs\flex\3.4.0.9271\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers

In my copy of SystemManager with the version of the SDK I have that line number doesn't make any sense since it's a block closure not an executable line so you'll have to look at your specific version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Flex 3.4 SDK.  Are you listening for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event when the application loads? Or doing anything with the Stage object on load?  If so, you might be hitting a bug specific to the 3.4 SDK:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-23332

The most obvious solution is to swap out the 3.4 SDK for a later version (3.4A, 3.5 or 3.6). You can do that here: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3

All of your code should be backwards compatable with the newer Flex 3 SDKs.